# A CallableStatement was executed with nothing returned

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a Java exception when calling a function that returns nothing:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A CallableStatement was executed with nothing returned.
```

The Java code is similar to this:

```
// Procedure call.
CallableStatement proc = con.prepareCall("{ ? = call doquery ( ? ) }");
proc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.Other);
proc.setInt(2, 33434);
proc.execute();
ResultSet results = (ResultSet) proc.getObject(1);
while (results.next()) {
  // do something with the results...
}
results.close();
proc.close();
```

The query is very simple:

```
select * from table where idTable = 33434;
```

The query does not return any value because what I'm looking for in postgresql DB does not exist. A sql query is like that, not always we get something in return.

How do you deal with this situations?

PS.- The Postgresql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION doquery(_idTable bigint)
  RETURNS TABLE(idTable bigint, name varchar) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    searchsql text := '';
BEGIN
    searchsql := 'SELECT * FROM table
            WHERE idTable = ' || _idTable;

    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE searchsql;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: show use your stored procedure, you need to make sure that your stored procedure returns something

Comment: I already attached the stored procedure!

Comment: I don't understand why you need a stored procedure to do such a simple query, could you please clarify?

Comment: This is just an experiment, what I need is a complex dynamic query. if this simple example can't work, how do I'm going to do a complex task?, it will be a waste of time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a CallableStatement. They are intended for stored *procedures* not functions.

As your function returns a resultset, you need to use a `select` statement:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from doquery(?)");
pstmt.setInt(1, 33434);

ResultSet results = pstmt.executeQuery();
while (results.next()) {
  // do something with the results...
}
results.close();
proc.close();
```

---

Note that the use of dynamic SQL or even PL/pgSQL is not needed. You should also not append parameters to queries (the same way you shouldn't do it in Java as well). Use parameter placeholders:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION doquery(_idTable bigint)
  RETURNS TABLE(idTable bigint, name varchar) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY 
       SELECT * 
       FROM table
       WHERE idTable = _idTable;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or even simpler as a pure SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION doquery(_idTable bigint)
  RETURNS TABLE(idTable bigint, name varchar) AS
$BODY$
   SELECT idtable, name 
   FROM table
   WHERE idTable = _idTable;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql;
```

---

If you **do** need dynamic SQL then use placeholders inside the string and pass the parameters to the execute function. Do not concatenate values:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION doquery(_idTable bigint)
  RETURNS TABLE(idTable bigint, name varchar) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
       SELECT * 
       FROM table
       WHERE idTable = $1'
    USING _idTable;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: If a CallableStatement shouldn't be used, because it is not intended for functions. How should you do it, if you are using a function? I know this example returns a result set and in that case a select statement would probably be better.
This Postgres documentation suggests using a callable statement when working with a function; https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/callproc.html

Comment: @Martin: not "probably better", but definitely better (for functions returning result sets) The example with a callable statement in the driver's manual is for scalar functions (returning a single value). Use whatever you prefer for them.